# Overload linking error

Tags: c++, linker, overloading, default

So I have a header with a default value function:

head.h:

```
a(int x, int y, bool* b = NULL);
```

head.cpp:

```
a(int x, int y, bool* b = NULL){...}
```

source.cpp:

```
a(1, 2, NULL);
a(1, 2);
```

and I'm getting an error on the linking stage:

```
undefined reference to a(int, int, bool*)
```

I have also tried removing the default value:

head.h:

```
a(int x, int y, bool* b);
a(int x, int y);
```

head.cpp:

```
a(int x, int y, bool* b){...}
a(int x, int y){...}
```

source.cpp:

```
a(1, 2, NULL);
a(1, 2);
```

linking with the same error:

```
undefined reference to a(int, int, bool*)
undefined reference to a(int, int)
```

What can this be? My compiler is bad? Bad makefile?

**EDIT**:

It seams the true header file looked like:

```
a(const int x, const int y, bool* b = NULL);
```

with `const`, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: can you show us the makefile , did you compile the source.cpp with header.cpp

Comment: you suspected compiler and makefile.  maybe tell us what compiler you use and post your makefile.

Comment: it's pretty much working and never causes problems even for huge projects.. cpp are compiled with gcc

Comment: if it's working, then what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: I'm asking the question that I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams I was defining the function in the header with `const` variables but implementing it in the cpp without the `const` therefore the linker failed to find the implementation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -o source source.cpp header.cpp` the command should be like this

I think you forget the header.cpp

Comment: it's not a makefile for specific file. it's a a dynamic makefile for big projects.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

First compile the program separately and generate object files

```
gcc -c header.c

gcc -c source.c
```

Then generate exe like this

```
gcc header.o source.o -o exefile
```